# Is there a cleaner (i.e. - faster) way to calculate in SQL during runtime?

Tags: sql

I have an SQL query that's calculating numbers inside it's `SELECT` statement. It's slowing the querytime down tremendously, and I can't help but figure there should be an easier way. I only have a very basic understanding for SQL and am tasked to alter an existing query containing the snippet below.

```
SELECT
    **Relevant Columns I want to see, i.e.:
    TableActual.Price AS [Final Pricing],
    **More columns
FROM
(
    SELECT
        a0.DocNum AS Ordernumber,
        a0.DocStatus AS OrderStatus,
        (
            SELECT 
                ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(b.Credit - b.Debit),2), 0)
            FROM 
                db.[dbo].ORDR a
                LEFT JOIN 
                db.[dbo].JDT1 b ON CAST(a.DocNum AS nvarchar(15)) = b.Project 
            WHERE  
                a.DocNum = a0.DocNum
                AND
                (
                    b.Account > '7999' 
                    AND
                    b.Account < '8701'
                )             
        ) AS Revenue, 
        ( 
            SELECT 
                ISNULL(ROUND((SUM(b.Credit - b.Debit) * - 1 ),2), 0)
            FROM 
                db.[dbo].ORDR a
                LEFT JOIN 
                db.[dbo].JDT1 b ON CAST(a.DocNum AS nvarchar(15)) = b.Project
            WHERE   
                a.DocNum = a0.DocNum
                AND
                ( 
                    b.Account = '7000' 
                    OR 
                    b.Account = '7010' 
                    OR 
                    b.Account = '7020' 
                )
        ) AS Price,
        ( 
            SELECT 
                ISNULL(ROUND((SUM(b.Credit - b.Debit) * - 1 ),2), 0) 
            FROM 
                db.[dbo].ORDR a
                LEFT JOIN 
                db.[dbo].JDT1 b ON CAST(a.DocNum AS nvarchar(15)) = b.Project
            WHERE 
                a.Docnum = a0.DocNum 
                AND 
                b.Account > 4000 
                AND 
                ( 
                    (
                        b.Account < 8000 
                        OR 
                        b.Account > 8700 
                    )
                    AND 
                    b.Account != 7000 
                    AND 
                    b.Account != 7010 
                    AND 
                    b.Account != 7020 
                    AND 
                    b.Account != 7250 
                ) 
        ) AS InstallationCosts

        FROM 
            db.[dbo].ORDR a0
        GROUP BY 
            a0.DocNum,
            a0.DocStatus
    ) AS TableActual
LEFT JOIN
    ** some more tables
```

I've already managed to pinpoint the issue, which is in the snippet above. In particular, I believe it's the lines `a.DocNum = a0.DocNum`. It appears to be iterating over all the database rows for every row it wants to add to the output. However, when I remove this `WHERE` statement, it will add all `ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(b.Credit - b.Debit),2), 0)` values together for each row.

So for example, where I would want my rows for the "Revenue" Column to list '5, 10, 25', it will list '40, 40, 40' instead.

When running this snippet in isolation, it'll take upwards of 30 seconds to complete. However, when I include it in the main query, it'll increase the query time from 15 seconds (main query without the snippet), to upwards of 15 minutes (main query with the snippet).

I've been playing around with the `a.DocNum = a0.DocNum` statement for a good half a day now, but I'm afraid my familiarity with SQL lacks severely to find a solution. The snippet has been written by a colleague for a different application, where it runs in isolation and the querytime is managable.

My next attempt to improve quertimes would be to combine the three select statements into one and attempt to retain the three output columns, hoping to cut runtime by two thirds at the very least.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, an appropriate database tag, and a clear explanation of what the code does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way :

```
            SELECT 
                ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN b.Account BETWEEN 7999 AND 870 THEN (b.Credit - b.Debit) ELSE NULL END),2), 0) Revenue
                , ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN b.Account IN (7000,7010, 7020) THEN (b.Credit - b.Debit) ELSE NULL END),2), 0) Price
                , ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN  b.Account > 4000 AND ((b.Account < 8000 OR b.Account > 8700) AND b.Account NOT IN (7000 ,7010,7020 ,7250) THEN (b.Credit - b.Debit) ELSE NULL END),2), 0) InstallationCosts 
            FROM 
                db.[dbo].ORDR a
                LEFT JOIN 
                db.[dbo].JDT1 b 
                    ON CAST(a.DocNum AS nvarchar(15)) = b.Project           

        GROUP BY 
            a.DocNum,
            a.DocStatus
```

Comment: yes, this is definitely in the right direction. It's decreased my querytime significantly. I was looking to do something just like that, but I was unfamiliar with the syntax you used in your `SELECT` statement. Thanks for steering me in the right direction!